# Enumerate with multiple numbers (comma-separated) for a single item

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'd like to get a list that looks like this:

```
1. Text addressing #1.

2,3. Text addressing #2 and #3 together.

4. Text addressing #4.
```

The motivation is that the list items are referring to a previous list. Any idea on how to do this easily with enumerate? (Or some other way to do it that looks consistent with the enumerate environment, i.e. if I had an enumerate list right above it, the two would seem to be formatted identically except the 2,3 part..)

Comment: I found this interesting, and I was searching for a solution for three numbers actually. Piggybacking on [egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108477/85959), I came up with \newcommand{\tripleitem}{% \begingroup \stepcounter{enumi}% \edef\tmp{\theenumi, }% \stepcounter{enumi} \edef\tmpt{\theenumi, } \stepcounter{enumi} \edef\tmp{\endgroup\noexpand\item[\tmp\tmpt\labelenumi]}% \tmp} for three numbers. Perhaps someone who knows more about the language would know how to generalize it for an arbitrary number of grouped items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need greater generality, this might work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\doubleitem}{%
  \begingroup
  \stepcounter{enumi}%
  \edef\tmp{\theenumi, }%
  \stepcounter{enumi}
  \edef\tmp{\endgroup\noexpand\item[\tmp\labelenumi]}%
  \tmp}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\end{enumerate}
Another
\begin{enumerate}
\item about A
\doubleitem about B and C
\item D
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]